# Firebase Cloud Functions - limit calls per second per IP

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am planing to create few API calls based on Firebase Cloud Functions and DB.

Every call will access to Firebase DB, get data or modify data in Firebase DB and return relevant responce.

But i am afraid of DDOS atacks, or similar massive access attacks.

By my usecase scenairio I am sure that user does not need more than 25 API calls in one minute.

Is it possible to set such limit to my Firebase Cloud Functions/DB ?

How can i protect my Firebase from overusing by unconscious individuals.

Answer (score -3):

```
private mylock:boolean = true;

if(this.mylock == true){

  do DB dquery//

  this.mylock = false;

   setTimeout(function(){ 
    this.mylock = true;
   }, 3000);

}
```

You could also look into Cloudflare to protect against attacks https://www.cloudflare.com/integrations/google-cloud/

But you might be going over the top, worrying about this... in a tin foil hat kind of way, it is quite rare for this to happen. I would simply put a budget alert in your billing section of Google Cloud that will flag up any large usage.

Comment: Thank you! Are you sure that global private variables are allowed on Firebase cloud functions?
Also i dont think this solution is what i am looking for. It will prevent from concurent work of many users.
i need to block all extra API calls if limit for specific IP address exceed.

Comment: My example is for a generic JavaScript/Angular response I would either email Firebase support directly there, may be a Google Firebase Group you could ask on or alternatively log each query with an ID an time base stamp in the DB and query the last one made